# Remove items from an array

Tags: php, arrays, array-unset

I have an array that is formatted as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [LASTNAME] => Name
            [FIRSTNAME] => Name
    )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [LASTNAME] => Name
            [FIRSTNAME] => Name
    )
```

and etc. I wish to remove the lastname and other items from each section of the array.

I've tried the following code, but to no avail.

```
foreach($s as $key => $object) {

    foreach($object as $key=>$value) {

            if ($key == "LASTNAME") {
                unset( $s['LASTNAME'] );
                }
            }
        }
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The inner loop is overwriting the outter's `$key` variable.

Comment: Well DUH!! That fixed it. Thank god I'm at a desk and not driving. Being this stupid could cause me to do some serious harm :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach ($s as &$object) {
    unset($object['LASTNAME']);
}
```

your problem is that you're operating on copies, `&` will give you reference, also as it is shown in my example you don't have to iterate over array to check if there is specific key inside, just remove it - `unset` will not rise any error if it is not there.

---

even in your example you're trying to remove `'LASTNAME'` from `$s` instead of its child, but anyway, just try my answer and it should work for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are unsetting from the wrong array.

Storing current key for each loop will help:

```
foreach($s as $key1 => $object) {
    foreach($object as $key2=>$value) {
        if ($key2 == "LASTNAME") {
            unset( $s[$key1][$key2] );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$array = Array(
    0 => Array(
            'id' => 1,
            'LASTNAME' => 'Name',
            'FIRSTNAME' => 'Name'
    ),
    1 => Array(
            'id' => 2,
            'LASTNAME' => 'Name',
            'FIRSTNAME' => 'Name'
    )
);

foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    unset($array[$key]['LASTNAME']);
}

echo '<pre>',print_r($array),'</pre>';
?>
```